# Probability for random vector given probability distribution

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, random-variables

Given the following probability distribution:

$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
xe^{-x-y},  & x,y>0 \\[2ex]
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$

compute $P(X \le Y)$. I know that the result is $1/4$, but I am not able to compute it. I tried the following:

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{0}^{y}f(x,y) \,dx\,dy,$$

but it does not work. Can you please explain to me what should I do?

Comment: "but it does not work" Why? Please show what you did.

Comment: The integral evaluates to 1/4 as required. Hence the confusion must lie with how you computed it, and without further information there is simply no way for any reader to identify _why_ it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**. Integrating by parts with respect to $x$ gives
$$
e^{-y}\int_{0}^{y}xe^{-x}dx=e^{-y}\left(1-e^{-y} (1+y)\right)=e^{-y}-(1+y)e^{-2y}
$$ integrating by parts once more with respect to $y$
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y}dy-\int_{0}^{\infty}(1+y)e^{-2y}dy=1-\frac34=\frac14.
$$

Comment: I thought that the idea for the double integral was wrong since I got $3/4$ and I even tried with WolframAlpha.